# How to capture text message in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, frontend, sentry

Goal:
Capture data in frontend with help of javascript with the hardcoded text message "testtest".
There is a similiar aproach for C# and the code is  "ravenClient.Capture(new SentryEvent("testtest"));"

Problem:
I cannot find a solution for javascript that is similiar approach for c# code "ravenClient.Capture(new SentryEvent("testtest"));"
I cannot find information about it at Docs "https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/".
Any idea about how to do it?

Info:
*Using bootstrap, jquery, vanilla javascript
*I'm newbie in Sentry

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In both the .NET and the JavaScript SDKs you can call `captureMessage`.

C#

```cs
SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("testtest");
```

[Documented here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/configuration/capture/#capturing-messages)

JavaScript

```js
Sentry.captureMessage("testtest")'
```

[Here for JavaScript](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/).

Please note the Raven SDKs were discontinued two years ago.

To install the new .NET SDK you can [see these docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/#install).

Creating a new project in Sentry will give you a wizard with steps to set things up for the selected technology.